# css arrow, caret, > with background

Tags: css

i'm trying to reproduce this https://gyazo.com/848fa4e24ecb33f220a465cdcf571698
only using css.

I got the "arrow" with the border properties and then rotate to the side i want with these css rules and the html:

```
border-right: 2px solid black;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
padding: 5px;
transform: rotate(-45deg);

<a href="#" class="right-arrow"></a>
```

But with i can't find a way to have that element with a background like the image on the link :/ 
Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-radius:50%` for the circle and for the angle use pseudo-class `::before` or `::after` to display it as `content`.

#### Demo

```css
.right-arrow {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #8AD82F;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

.right-arrow::after {
  content: '\a0\a0\276f';
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="right-arrow"></a>
```